# Iterating multiple textviews with onClickListeners

Tags: java, android, textview, onclicklistener

I am setting up a textView Keyboard for a vocabulary game. I am looking to clean up my code and was wondering if I could iterate all 26 letters. As of now I declare them all 
individually as shown in the code.

I would like to use a for loop and have experimented with no luck.

```
private void setupKeyBoard() {
    A = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.A);
    A.setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    A.setText("A");
    A.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkGuess('A');
            A.setClickable(false);
            A.setAlpha((float) .1);
        }
    });

    B = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.B);
    B.setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    B.setText("B");
    B.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkGuess('B');
            B.setClickable(false);
            B.setAlpha((float) .1);
        }
    });

    C = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.C);
    C.setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    C.setText("C");
    C.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkGuess('C');
            C.setClickable(false);
            C.setAlpha((float) .1);
        }
    });
} //stop at Z
```

Comment: are you have 26 TextView in your layout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend this method :

```
for(char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z';letter ++){
int letterID = getResources().getIdentifier(""+letter, "id", getPackageName());
TextView txtview = (TextView) getView().findViewById(letterID);
    txtview .setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    txtview .setText(letter);
    txtview .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkGuess(letter);
            txtview.setClickable(false);
            txtview.setAlpha((float) .1);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking and I tried something similar. When trying your code I get these errors. "Cannot resolve method 'getPackageName()" and "Variable 'txtview' is accessed from within inner class. Needs to be declared final" andVariable 'letter' is accessed from within inner class. Needs to be declared final.

Comment: txtview need to be final. If you are using fragments add getActivity().getPackageName()

Answer (score 0):

A better to make the textviews is create your own textviews in a loop and store it in a hashmap with a single id so you can get each one with out a problem. But if you want to get all one maybe you can do this from a parent you can do this:

```
String[] lettersMap = {"A", "B", "C",....,"Z"};

HashMap<String, TextView> map = new HashMap<String, TextView>();

// ll is your linear layout or your relative (i.e. your parent of all the textviews)
int childcount = ll.getChildCount();

for (int i=0, letMap = 0; i < childcount; i++){
      View v = ll.getChildAt(i);

     if (v instanceof TextView) {
          TextView tv = (TextView) v;
          tv.setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
          tv.setText(lettersMap[letMap]);
          tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {
            checkGuess(lettersMap[letMap]);
            tv.setClickable(false);
            tv.setAlpha((float) .1);
        }
    });

map.put(lettersMap[letMpa], tv);
     }
}
```